# Linq Count(condition) is not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In the following Linq query, the generated SQL ignores the c.val != null check in Count()

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on t1.col1 equals t2.col1
where t1.col1 = 123 && t3.Count(c => c.val != null && c.col1 == t1.col1) == 0
select new {t1.col1, t2.col2, t1.col2}
```

it is translated to

```
SELECT [t0].[col1], [t1].[col2], [t0].[col2]
FROM [t1] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [t2] AS [t1] ON [t0].[col1] = [t1].[col1]
WHERE ([t0].[col1] = @p0) AND (((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [t3] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[col1] = [t0].[col1]
    )) = @p1)
```

whereas when written the following only

```
t.Count(c => c.ID != null && t.No > 10)
```

it is translated to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [t] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[ID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t0].[No] > @p0)
```

Here it is not skipping the c.ID != null check. Why is this behavior occurring? Are there any restrictions on the use of Count inside a where clause?

Comment: Maybe id is nullable but val is not.

Comment: That's right! I totally missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of optimalisation. In sql is null=null false, this explains why you do not need the extra is null check in your first expression (smart rewrite in Linq). The transaltion of the second expression is not with a == so different optimalization are used. In this case the parser did no see that ([t0].[ID] IS NOT NULL) does not add any value in de sql expression.

Comment: Yes, Linq does perform optimizations. I experimented with the query and it did perform the optimization to avoid the extra code from it.  @sgmoore 's suggestion was the situation in my case though.